# Filter in list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to add a condition to this list comprehension so that its result does not contain empty strings:

```
words = [regex.sub('\P{alpha}','',word) for word in words]
```

Answer (score 4):

Move it into a generator expression and do a list comprehension over that.

```
words = [x for x in (regex.sub('\P{alpha}', '', word) for word in words) if x]
```

Comment: @Why might you do this as a oneliner instead of breaking it into two lines?

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to post-process the resulting list (and convert the result to a list, per Ashwini's comment):

```
words = list(filter(None, (regex.sub('\P{alpha}','',word) for word in words)))
```

You can also pass your original list comprehension as the 2nd argument:

```
words = filter(None, [regex.sub('\P{alpha}','',word) for word in words])
```

The first is probably more efficient if you expect many of the substitutions to produce empty strings.

---

Here's a solution using `itertools` and `functools`, for functional-style fans:

```
from itertools import imap, filter
from functools import partial
modifier = partial(regex.sub, '\P{alpha}', '')
words = list(ifilter(None, imap(modifier, words)))
```

Comment: To get a list pass the result of filter to `list()`.

Comment: The question says Python3, so no need to import from itertools. You _do_ still need to convert the result of filter to a list though.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for alpha characters in the word:

```
[regex.sub('\P{alpha}','',word) for word in words if list(filter(str.isalpha, word))]
```

This can already be faster than the other approaches (it depends on whether there are words that become empty strings), but then you might as well not use the regular expression:

```
[x for x in ("".join(filter(str.isalpha, word)) for word in words) if x]
```

This is quite faster (tested on Python 2.7) and, in my opinion, doesn't hurt readability much, although it is a bit uglier than in Python 2.7, where I originally tested.